# Transfer data generated by an external interrupt from a C++ program to Java in Linux

Tags: java, c++, linux, embedded, interrupt

I'm looking for a method of transferring data acquired using an external interrupt and a C++ program to a Java program. The rate at which data is acquired varies slightly (hence the interrupt-driven acquisition) and must be made available to another Java program running parallel to the C++ program.

Both programs are running on an embedded Linux-based OS.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)? They're designed for pretty much exactly what you want to do. Just have the C++ program output to the pipe, and have the Java program read it in like any other file.